# Segmentation fault with cvCopy inside of an IplImage* table (IplImage**)

Tags: c, opencv, iplimage

I have to keep in memory a predefined number of images. 
I'have created an array like this :

```
int nb_frame_decalage=10;
IplImage** accumulateur_image;
CvCapture* capture;
IplImage* Image_B_Brut;


capture=cvCreateFileCapture("./Data/video2.avi");
if (!capture) {printf("\nOuverture du flux vidéo impossible !\n");key='k';}
image_B_brut = cvQueryFrame(capture);


accumulateur_image=malloc(sizeof(IplImage*)*nb_frame_decalage);
int i;
for (i=0;i<nb_frame_decalage;i++)
{
    accumulateur_image[i]=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image_B_brut),
    image_B_brut->depth,
    image_B_brut->nChannels);
}
add_image(&accumulateur_image,image_B_brut,nb_frame_decalage);
```

I loop on cvCapture after that, but it give an error in the first call of this function :
I want to add Element to the end of this list...

```
void add_image(IplImage*** accumulateur,IplImage* Image_to_add,int taille_accumulateur)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<taille_accumulateur;i++)
    {
        cvCopy((*accumulateur)[i+1],(*accumulateur)[i],NULL);
    }
    cvCopy(Image_to_add,*accumulateur[taille_accumulateur],NULL);
}
```

It compile but it seems to be a problem in the add_image function, because a segmentation fault appear when the program come in this function.

Does someone already have this mistake ?

**EDIT AFTER ANSWER**

Finaly, this code works, i modified index add_image function.

```
int nb_frame_decalage=10;
IplImage** accumulateur_image;
CvCapture* capture;
IplImage* Image_B_Brut;


capture=cvCreateFileCapture("./Data/video2.avi");
if (!capture) {printf("\nOuverture du flux vidéo impossible !\n");key='k';}
image_B_brut = cvQueryFrame(capture);


accumulateur_image=malloc(sizeof(IplImage*)*nb_frame_decalage);
int i;
for (i=0;i<nb_frame_decalage;i++)
{
    accumulateur_image[i]=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image_B_brut),
    image_B_brut->depth,
    image_B_brut->nChannels);
}
add_image(&accumulateur_image,image_B_brut,nb_frame_decalage);


void add_image(IplImage*** accumulateur,IplImage* Image_to_add,int taille_accumulateur)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<taille_accumulateur-1;i++)
    {
        cvCopy((*accumulateur)[i+1],(*accumulateur)[i],NULL);
    }
    cvCopy(Image_to_add,(*accumulateur)[taille_accumulateur-1],NULL);
}
```

Thanks to alk for his helpful answer.

Comment: That's not a list, it's an array. [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). And show more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you call `add_image()` like this

```
add_image(accumulateur_image, ..., nb_frame_decalage);
```

then the following line access `*accumulateur` out of bounds:

```
  cvCopy((*accumulateur)[i+1], ... /* for i=taille_accumulateur */
```

Accessing an array out of bounds provokes undefinded behaviour, which in many cases result in a segmentation violation aka segfault.

---

Also this

```
cvCopy(Image_to_add,*accumulateur[taille_accumulateur],NULL);
```

shall be

```
cvCopy(Image_to_add, (*accumulateur)[taille_accumulateur], NULL);
```

as the `[]` operator binds tighter then the `*` operator. But even if fixed as shown the code might access `*accumulateur` out of bounds under the assumption made above.